# Checking if a session is bridged to another one

Tags: javascript, freeswitch

I've got a js Freeswitch script where caller has to call another number after a digit.
I've just made a bridge in this way

```
let callee_number = <called number>;
let paramBLeg = "{ignore_early_media=true,hangup_after_bridge=true,origination_caller_id_number=<caller>,origination_caller_id_name=<caller>}";
let gateway = "<gateway id>";

let BLeg= paramBLeg+"sofia/gateway/"+gateway+"/"+callee_number;

session.execute("bridge", BLeg);
```

But I can't have a feed if Leg A is bridged with Leg B.
How can I check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you need this
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=3965124#content/view/3965124

```
if (session:bridged() == true) do
-- Do something
end
```